# Outlook AddIn (NetOffice) - Context Menu

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, netoffice

I'm using [NetOffice](https://netoffice.codeplex.com/) developing an MS Outlook AddIn, and I want to add a custom context menu item in the calendar, to allow users add a new custom appointment for the selected time range.

So as written in this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691832%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#odc_office2010_CustomizeContextMenus_IntroductionCustomizingContextMenus) I define my additional item in the RibbonUI.xml following way:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="OnLoadRibonUI">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabAppointment">
        <group id="Group0" label="Addin" insertBeforeMso="GroupShow">
          <button id="convertButton" label="Convert" getImage="ConvertImage" size="large" onAction="ConvertButton_Click" />
        </group>
      </tab>
      <tab idMso="TabCalendar">
        <group id="Group1" label="Addin" insertBeforeMso="GroupGoto">
          <button id="aboutButton" label="New Custom Meeting" getImage="GetNewImage" size="large" onAction="NewMeetingButton_Click" />
          <dialogBoxLauncher>
            <button id="settingsButton" screentip="Addin Settings" onAction="SettingsButton_Click"/>
          </dialogBoxLauncher>
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
  <contextMenus>    
      <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuCalendarView">
          <button id="MyContextMenuCalendarView" 
              label="ContextMenuCalendarView" 
              onAction="OnMyButtonClick"/>
      </contextMenu>  
  </contextMenus>
</customUI>
```

But as soon as I add the `<contextMenus>` node, the xml isn't working anymore, not the add in doesn't add any context menu, but it also doesn't add any buttons anymore - whereas the buttons are added when the `<contextMenus>` node is not defined.
Any tips how to debug this issue?

EDIT:

thanks to the tip from Dmitry I found the issue the `xmlns` namespace was an old one, so instead of:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui"
```

it should be:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong off the top of my head, but enable the dev mode in Outlook - this way Outlook will report all problems in your XML. Click `File | Options | Advanced | Developers | Show add-in user interface errors`.

Comment: Thanks! This pointed me to the issue (solution added to my question) - and I guess it will point me to many issues in the future. Didn't know about this option :)